# Anyone know why my cards won't show up? (HTML, Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to follow along on Colt Steele's course and for some reason, my cards will not show up. Anyone know why my cards won't show up? I'm trying to do three image overlay cards that are decked with equal spacing between each other by using some basic bootstrap add-ins but they won't even show up.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style>
    #header {
      background-image: url("imgs/header.jpeg");
    }
  </style>

  <title>Pattern</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Quarantine Pal</a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section id="header" class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1 class="display-3">Best 90s Anime</h1>
    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Add to List</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-success">Vote</a>
  </section>

  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://dw9to29mmj727.cloudfront.net/properties/2016/432-SeriesThumbnails_SM__400x320.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Sailor Moon">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Sailor Moon</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://dw9to29mmj727.cloudfront.net/properties/2016/15-SeriesThumbnailsAnime_INY_400x320.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Inuyasha">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Inuyasha</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.39852.14455250034361967.824623c3-91b6-402f-9a68-c66bfac9bc20.7bfae929-5b2a-4efe-9639-5ffd1e2de297?mode=scale&q=90&h=720&w=1280&background=%23FFFFFF" class="card-img-top" alt="Dragon Ball Z">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Dragon Ball Z</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Shows just fine to me in the snippet I made you